# LogicApp Pagination with Salesforce GetRecords

Tags: salesforce, azure-logic-apps

[image]

There is over 300K records and I have Pagination turned on with 1000 threshold.
[image]

However I am not getting all the records?

Comment: So what are you getting? I’m confused, is the issue to do with pagination or not getting all the records?

Comment: I am only getting back 50K records when there is 300K to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

**AFAIK ** You **cannot retrieve more than 50,000 records your SOQL calls in a single context**. However, with Batch Apex your logic will be processed in chunks of anywhere from 1 to 200 records in a batch. You'd need to modify your business logic to take the batching into account if necessary.
Here are the reference [documents](https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/how-to-fetch-more-than-50k-records-using-soql-in-salesforce/#:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20retrieve%20more%20than%2050,000%20records%20your,to%20take%20the%20batching%20into%20account%20if%20necessary.) for this

If you're okay with apex model to retrieve more than 50k/1 million records through apex class in salesforce, follow this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I9BWQA0)

Get records from salesforce using [Logic App](https://www.cloudfronts.com/azure/how-to-get-records-from-salesforce-using-logic-app-2/)

Get bulk data with [Pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination)

Comment: I tried to follow the Get records from salesforce using Logic App you mentioned but do not know what they mean on Step 3 because step 2 and 3 look the same.  How does the total-records and page-number get set?